# What is the purpose of "Macros for minimum-width integer constants"

Tags: c, integer, c99

In C99 standard Section 7.18.4.1 "Macros for minimum-width integer constants", some macros defined as `[U]INT[N]_C(x)` for casting constant integers to least data types where N = 8, 16, 32, 64. Why are these macros defined since I can use L, UL, LL or ULL modifiers instead? For example, when I want to use *at least* 32 bits unsigned constant integer, I can simply write `42UL` instead of `UINT32_C(42)`. Since long data type is at least 32 bits wide it is also portable.

So, what is the purpose of these macros?

Comment: I think they're so that you don't have to worry about such things as how big an `int`, or a `long` is when creating your own types of fixed sized integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need them in places where you want to make sure that they don't become too wide

```
#define myConstant UINT32_C(42)
```

and later

```
printf( "%" PRId32 " is %s\n", (hasproperty ? toto : myConstant), "rich");
```

here, if the constant would be `UL` the expression might be `ulong` and the variadic function could put a 64bit value on the stack that would be misinterpreted by `printf`.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that long can be 64-bits on some 32-bits platforms? Therefore it would be problematic in some functions like printf. If so, it would have also a performance impact, because 64-bits integer manipulation occur when 32-bits is enough.

Comment: yes, this is up to the platform designers to decide. And don't overestimate performance difference for operations on integers of different width, on modern machines there is none for the arithmetic itself. The only difference could be if you are doing a lot of such operations in a loop and the access to memory would be a bottleneck. In the contrary, modern avx processors do 256 bit operations as fast as 32 bit operations, so generally it is a bad idea to chose types of a specified width. Use `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t` and things like that  that fit the semantics of what you are doing.

Comment: Are there any 16 bit compilers where static `const uint32_t var = 0xFFFF0000;` could result in var = 0x0000? What do the C99 and C89 specs say about the size of a constant?

Comment: @Samuel: no. The constant has always a type that fits it. And since its value fits into 32 bits, there will never be a loss of information, here.

Comment: This is not a good example. The minimum-width integer constant macros might add an integer constant suffix (such as `L`, `LL`, `U`, `UL` or `ULL`), but that won't downcast the argument like a regular cast would. You do `printf( "%" PRIu32 "\n", UINT32_C(42000000000));` and bam, your program is undefined.

Comment: @PSkocik, I don't see that. Sure that if you put a constant that doesn't fit into the type the behavior might be undefined. But decent compilers warn about that, so this is a minor problem. On the other hand if you downcast to the type, you get another value and your program is incorrect and no compiler can ever warn you. I prefer the former.

Answer (score 3):

They use the *smallest* integer type with a width of at least N, so `UINT32_C(42)` is only equivalent to `42UL` on systems where `int` is smaller than 32 bits. On systems where `int` is 32 bits or greater, `UINT32_C(42)` is equivalent to `42U`. You could even imagine a system where a `short` is 32 bits wide, in which case `UINT32_C(42)` would be equivalent to `(unsigned short)42`.

EDIT: @obareey It seems that most, if not all, implementations of the standard library do not comply with this part of the standard, perhaps because it is impossible. [[glibc bug 2841](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2841)] [[glibc commit b7398be5](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=b7398be5f8ce235f78cf92b21c39f00c150ffe68)]

Comment: But on those platforms it doesn't matter if 32-bits is short, because it would be the fastest integer with at least 32-bits, or I thought as so. Now I'm confused. Because it writes "The macro UINTN_C(value) shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type uint_leastN_t" in the standard, but 32-bits ARM compiler defines "#define UINT8_C(x)  (x ## u)" and "#define UINT16_C(x) (x ## u)" without any casting.

Comment: I wonder how often any of these macros actually get used to make code more portable?  The semantics of things like signed-versus-unsigned comparisons have so many weird and quirky corner cases I can't see how one could possibly hope to cope with them all.  For example, given `uint32_t n`, what would be the behavior of `(n-1) < UINT32_C(5);` if `n` is zero?  How would one best write that expression to be portable on system with `int` larger than, smaller than, or equal to 32 bits?

Answer (score 0):

The macros essentially possibly add an integer constant suffix such as
`L`, `LL`, `U`, `UL`, o `UL` to their argument, which basically makes them almost equivalent to the corresponding cast, except that the suffix won't ever downcast.

E.g., 
`UINT32_C(42000000000)` (42 billion) on an LLP64 architecture will turn into `42000000000U`, which will have type `UL` subject to the [rules explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47206691/1084774). The corresponding cast, on the other hand (`(uint32_t)42000000000`), would truncate it down to `uint32_t` (`unsigned int` on LLP64).

I can't think of a good use case, but I imagine it could be usable in some generic bit-twiddling macros that need at least X bits to work, but don't want to remove any extra bits if the user passes in something bigger.