# INT_MIN and its positive equivalent is the same size

Tags: c

I would expect -2147483648 to be able to fit into 4 bytes because it is represented using 2's complement.

Am I missing something?

```
INT MIN: -2147483648
INT MAX: 2147483647
sizeof -2147483647: 4 
sizeof 2147483647: 4 
sizeof -2147483648: 8
sizeof 2147483648: 8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-2147483648` is `2147483648`, a `long` number on your platform (because it's a decimal* greater than `INT_MAX` that fits in a `long`), negated.
Numbers in C (and the C preprocessor) are parsed separately from the `-` unary operator. That is why e.g., the glibc implementation of the standard C library implements the `INT_MIN` macro as `(-INT_MAX - 1)`.

---

*The [rules determining what type to use for an integer literal with or without a suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47206691/1084774) differ depending on the radix of the literal.